# Change cursor of Spacemacs from box to vertical line for all themes

Tags: elisp, spacemacs

I have installed some themes for Spacemacs, and some of them make the cursor appear as a vertical line (like in Sublime or Atom), while some make the cursor appear as a solid box (like the default theme of Spacemacs).

Is there any way to set the cursor appearance to a vertical line for all themes?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the variable `cursor-type` in your `.spacemacs`-file by adding

`(setq-default cursor-type 'bar)`

You can see all possible cursor types using `M-x describe-variable RET cursor-type RET`.